# Swagger OpenApi 3.0 not allowing a PUT requests only POST and GET work

Tags: cors, swagger-ui, openapi

I have a ***PUT*** requests that will not go thru on ***OPENAPI 3.0*** I get the CORS issue but funny thing is that if I take the ***CURL*** request that SwaggerUI builds and put it into any CLI it works flawlessly. Only thru SwaggerUI that ***PUT*** does not work. ***POST*** and ***GET*** no problem.

***Failed to fetch. 

Possible Reasons: 

CORS 

Network Failure 

URL scheme must be "http" or "https" for CORS request.***

If I get my JSON file definition it reads as below. I can see that PUT is not in the "Access-Control-Allow-Methods" but I don't know how to add it.

***$ curl -I "http://192.168.2.120:8087/medic/ic-swagger.json" 

HTTP/1.1 200 OK 

Server: nginx 

Date: Tue, 27 Jul 2021 14:55:25 GMT 

Content-Type: application/json 

Content-Length: 25275 

Last-Modified: Tue, 27 Jul 2021 14:54:22 GMT 

Connection: keep-alive 

ETag: "61001e1e-62bb" 

Expires: Tue, 27 Jul 2021 14:55:24 GMT 

Cache-Control: no-cache 

Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * 

Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS 

Access-Control-Allow-Headers: DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If- 

Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type 

Accept-Ranges: bytes***

The simple PUT request below

```
/user/login:
  put:
    tags: [GETTING STARTED]
    summary: Log a user in.
    description: Log a user in and get an Id.
    requestBody:
      required: true
      content:
        text/plain:
          schema:
            $ref: '#/components/schemas/loginBody'
    responses:
      '200':
        description: Successful user login. RESULT will hold the new Id
        content:
          application/json:
            schema:
              $ref: '#/components/schemas/Login_response_1'
```

Thru POSTMAN no problem and in the header you find:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, PUT, UPDATE, OPTIONS, HEAD 
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

Any help would be appreaciated.

Comment: 1) What's the full error message in the Console tab in the browser dev tools? 2) Unrelated comment: the content type in the `requestBody` should probably be `application/json` instead of `text/plain`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well, I figured it out from some old code but can't remember why this works ***or if it is the correct solution***, if someone can explain, please. So what I found out is that if I add an ***OPTIONS*** REST call then everything works perfectly. It seems that preflight goes there and gets the Access-Control-Allow-Origin and then allows the call to go thru.

```
    @OPTIONS
@Path("user/login")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response optionsLogin() {
    
    Response.ResponseBuilder res = 
    
     Response.ok()
            .header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
            .header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true")
            .header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, PUT, UPDATE, OPTIONS, HEAD")
            .header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Accept, X-Requested-With");
    
    return res.build();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Do you use some kind of ad blocker? If yes, you can try to disable it.

Answer (score -1):

To resolve the CORS problem when you do a PUT with body content, your remote application must add in the response headers:

Access-Control-Allow-Methods: PUT

Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type

Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * (or https://my-swagger.example.com)